# How to compare 2 dataframes columns and add a value to a new dataframe based on the result

Tags: pandas, compare

I have 2 dataframes with the same length, and I'd like to compare specific columns between them. If the value of the first column in one of the dataframe is bigger - i'd like it to take the value in the second column and assign it to a new dataframe.
See example. The first dataframe:

```
       0   class
0    1.9       0
1    9.8       0
2    4.5       0
3    8.1       0
4    1.9       0
```

The second dataframe:

```
       0   class
0    1.4       1
1    7.8       1
2    8.5       1
3    9.1       1
4    3.9       1
```

The new dataframe should look like:

```
  class
0     0
1     0
2     1
3     1
4     1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with `DataFrame` constructor:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'class': np.where(df1[0] > df2[0], df1['class'], df2['class'])})
```

Or [`DataFrame.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html):

```
df = df1[['class']].where(df1[0] > df2[0], df2[['class']])
```

---

```
print (df)
   class
0      0
1      0
2      1
3      1
4      1
```

EDIT:

If there is another condition use [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) and if necessary [`numpy.isclose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html)

```
print (df2)
     0  class
0  1.4      1
1  7.8      1
2  8.5      1
3  9.1      1
4  1.9      1


masks = [df1[0] == df2[0], df1[0] > df2[0]]
#if need compare floats in some accuracy
#masks = [np.isclose(df1[0], df2[0]), df1[0] > df2[0]]
vals = ['not_determined', df1['class']]
df = pd.DataFrame({'class': np.select(masks, vals, df2['class'])})
print (df)
            class
0               0
1               0
2               1
3               1
4  not_determined
```

Or:

```
masks = [df1[0] == df2[0], df1[0] > df2[0]]
vals = ['not_determined', 1]
df = pd.DataFrame({'class': np.select(masks, vals, 1)})
print (df)
            class
0               0
1               0
2               1
3               1
4  not_determined
```

Solution for out of box:

```
df = np.sign(df1[0].sub(df2[0])).map({1:0, -1:1, 0:'not_determined'}).to_frame('class')
print (df)
            class
0               0
1               0
2               1
3               1
4  not_determined
```

Comment: thanks! That's perfect. How do handle cases in which the values are identical? let's say I'd like it to write 'not_determined' in those cases

Comment: @Bella - hmmm, give me some time.

Comment: beautiful solutions!

Answer (score 2):

Since class is 0 and 1, you could try,

```
df1[0].lt(df2[0]).astype(int)
```

For generic solutions, check jezrael's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df_1
     0  class
0  1.9      0
1  9.8      0
2  4.5      0
3  8.1      0
4  1.9      0
>>> df_2
     0  class
0  1.4      1
1  7.8      1
2  8.5      1
3  9.1      1
4  3.9      1
>>> df_3=pd.DataFrame()
>>> df_3["class"]=np.where(df_1["0"]>df_2["0"], df_1["class"], df_2["class"])
>>> df_3
   class
0      0
1      0
2      1
3      1
4      1
```